# r subset based on 2 dynamic conditions

Tags: r, dynamic, subset

I would like to create a data-frame-subset based on variables. I can do it for 1 variable using eval and expression, but can't find an example which works for 2 or more conditions.

```
 set.seed(1)
 df<-data.frame(N=letters[1:10],y=runif(10)*3)
 df$M<-ceiling(df$y)

 # N=b & M=2 are my "dynamic" conditions:
 N<-"b"
 M<-2
 subex<-cat("N==\"",N,"\" & M==",M,"",sep="")
 # gives: N=="b" & M==2

 sdf<-subset(df,eval(expression(subex)),) # --> error
 # Error in subset.data.frame(df, eval(expression(subex)), ) : 
 #  'subset' must be boolean

 # the code itself works
 sdf2<-subset(df,N=="b" & M==2,)
 # gives desired result: 
 # N        y M
 # 2 b 1.116372 2
```

Comment: I think you meant `paste` instead of `cat` as `subex` is NULL if you check ity i.e. `subex<- paste("N==\"",N,"\" & M==",M,"",sep=""); df[with(df, eval(parse(text=subex))),, drop=FALSE]`

Comment: Why not: `df[ df$N == N & df$M == M, ]` ?

Comment: Thanks akrun & zx8754. I did not realize that the expression in fact was empty (only looked in the console).

Comment: (I think it's obvious, I am a newbie), but after I found that my filters in fact where empty I eventually find the bquote function and the subset code works now. Thanks akrun! (If I could, I would have marked your reply as answer, but I instead I only could mark your as helpful.)